# Dimension of irreducible totally-symmetric tensor product of two su(n) representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, tensor-products, young-tableaux

Consider the irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{su}$(n) given by the Young tableu

[image]

The dimension of the representation is easily obtained by the [usual rules](https://www.physics.mcgill.ca/%7Ekeshav/673IV/youngtableaux.pdf), and it is $d=n(n-1)/2$. One can also directly guess $d$ by noting that the antisymmetric tensor product of two fundamental representations (with dimension $n$) has a base of $\begin{pmatrix} n \\ 2\end{pmatrix}=n(n-1)/2$ elements.

For concreteness, let me fix in the following $n=4$ and consider the totally symmetric product of two representations as above

[image]

where $\cdot$ is the trivial 1-dimensional representation ($n=4$ here)

With the [rules](https://www.physics.mcgill.ca/%7Ekeshav/673IV/youngtableaux.pdf) for computing the dimension of the irreducible representations, the dimension of $\Gamma_1$ is $d(\Gamma_1) = n^2(n^2-1)/12 = 20$.

Alternatively, given the dimension $d=6$ of the representation in the first figure, I could have thought that [the symmetric tensor product](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/94036/867427) of two such representation has the dimension $\begin{pmatrix}d+2-1\\ 2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}7\\2\end{pmatrix}=21$.

What is wrong in the second line of reasoning? Why cannot I compute the dimension of $\Gamma_1$ with the [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/94036/867427) for symmetric tensor products?

Comment: Why do you think the symmetric square of the $6$-dimensional representation is irreducible and equal to $\Gamma_1$? Why is it not $\Gamma_1\oplus $ trivial?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Uhm, is this the problem? If I take the tensor products of S defining representations, the fully symmetrized representation is irreducible and corresponds to young tableau of 1 row and S element. Is this the problem, i.e., that in general the fully-symmetrized representation is *not* irreducible and does *not* correspond to the young tableau obtained stacking together the tableux horizontally?

Comment: The symmetric square of artbitrary representations is not irreducible in general, no.

Comment: More concretely what is happening here is that there is an invariant symmetric bilinear form on the representation which corresponds to a trivial subrep of the symmetric square